# is it possible to have vertical SWT controls?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to have some of the controls in an app - `Button`s and `Label`s - vertically oriented - . However i could not find a possibilty to do this. Even the non-public setOrientation method tackles only the left-to-right orientation.
Is it possible without implementing a custom `Button` or deriving from `Canvas`?

Comment: Now you can do this. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8091920/796559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know vertical orientation for Button and Label is not possible.
You will need to provide custom implementation for same.
Check this link http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg30094.html

Comment: its a shame, but ill have do do it myself :( maybe e4 will improve on that

Comment: @kostja - e4 will still use SWT and native controls. As long as those native controls don't provide vertical orientation or some sort of rotation of controls or components, there's no way other then fully java based controls (like Swing)

Answer (score 3):

SWT uses the standard widgets provided by the host operating system. So if the operating system does not provide support for vertically oriented controls, SWT can't provide it too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible in `SWT` using custom widget. 
You need to make your own `Button` / `Label`. 
In the `PaintListener` , get the `Transform` object and rotate the text to your desired angle. 
In the example for every click , change the angle to this sequence 0,90,180,270.
The `button`(here actually `Canvas`) aspect ratio is changed by setting the `bounds`.
Feel free to play with the `paint` method;

```
public class RotatingButton extends Canvas
{
    private int     mouse           = 0;
    private boolean hit             = false;
    private String  text            = "Button";
    float           rotatingAngle   = 0f;
    float[]         angles          = { 0, 90, 180, 270 };
    int             index           = 0;
public RotatingButton(Composite parent, int style)
{
    super(parent, style);

    this.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener()
    {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            index++;
            index = index > 3 ? 0 : index;
                Rectangle r = getBounds();

                setBounds(r.x, r.y, r.height, r.width);


            rotatingAngle = angles[index];
            redraw();
        }
    });
    this.addPaintListener(new PaintListener()
    {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
        {
            paint(e);
        }
    });
    this.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener()
    {
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (!hit)
                return;
            mouse = 2;
            if (e.x < 0 || e.y < 0 || e.x > getBounds().width
                    || e.y > getBounds().height)
            {
                mouse = 0;
            }
            redraw();
        }
    });
    this.addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent e)
        {
            mouse = 1;
            redraw();
        }

        public void mouseExit(MouseEvent e)
        {
            mouse = 0;
            redraw();
        }
    });
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
        {
            hit = true;
            mouse = 2;
            redraw();
        }

        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
        {
            hit = false;
            mouse = 1;
            if (e.x < 0 || e.y < 0 || e.x > getBounds().width
                    || e.y > getBounds().height)
            {
                mouse = 0;
            }
            redraw();
            if (mouse == 1)
                notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
        }
    });
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == '\r' || e.character == ' ')
            {
                Event event = new Event();
                notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setText(String string)
{
    this.text = string;
    redraw();
}

public void paint(PaintEvent e)
{
    Transform tr = null;
    tr = new Transform(e.display);

    Rectangle r =getBounds();
    text=e.gc.stringExtent(text)+"";
    e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
    Point p=e.gc.stringExtent(text);
    int w = e.width;
    int h = e.height;
    tr.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
    tr.rotate(rotatingAngle);
    e.gc.setTransform(tr);
    e.gc.drawString(text, r.x-(p.x/3)*2,r.y-p.y);
}
}
```

[image: Screen SHOT]