# Displaying text on a swt button vertically

Tags: text, swt

I'm trying to display text on a button. Instead of displaying it as "Vertical", I'd like to display it as

```
V
e
r
t
i
c
a
l
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your own widget to achieve it in SWT. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33966218/1172155) is a complete example that you can try. Hope it helps.

[image: here is the output of the program when clicked]

Answer (score 0):

SWT buttons do support wrapping (since 3.7).

```
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH | SWT.WRAP);
button.setText("V\ne\nr\nt\ni\nc\na\nl");
```

But unfortunately the lines will be centered as a whole and not individually, so the result does not look particularly good.

Comment: Add `SWT.CENTER` to the style of the `Button` - that will do the trick.

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately `SWT.CENTER` does *not* change anything.